# Malicious files generating in CentOS 7 directory /usr/bin

Tags: linux, centos7, malicious

I installed a CentOS 7 at my Virtual Machine,

As i have installed the antivirus on the machine i found some files in /usr/bin which coming as Malicious content, i backup them and again they generated with another names, and names are randoms. Can someone guide me what kind of files are, is it really any Malicious Script which generating files. below are the files for the reference.

```
rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    625889 Jun 14 17:58 zqoppdtajj_bkp_ali  #i marked them backup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       156 Jun 14 17:58 saxquzl.sh_bkp_ali #i marked them backup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       158 Jun 14 20:19 nntbxqpwp.sh_blk_script #i marked them backup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    625878 Jun 14 20:19 rpsdbuuyef_bkp_ali #i marked them backup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       161 Jun 20 13:46 plhurveidhxc.sh_bkp_ali #i marked them backup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       160 Jun 20 13:47 ezkxscupeqn.sh_bk_ali #i marked them backup

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    562340 Jun 20 13:49 uhrxms
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       155 Jun 20 13:49 smxrhu.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    562340 Jun 20 13:49 smxrhu
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    559794 Jun 20 13:50 zkjqbal
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    559794 Jun 20 13:50 labqjkz
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       156 Jun 20 13:50 labqjkz.sh
```

inside the smxrhu.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin
cp "/usr/bin/smxrhu" "/usr/bin/mrpjpymvkc"
"/usr/bin/mrpjpymvkc"
```

Inside the labqjkz.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin
cp "/usr/bin/labqjkz" "/usr/bin/ivsuvtlkzx"
"/usr/bin/ivsuvtlkzx"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely these are something you do not want on your system. You should restore the system from backups that you know are good.

Comment: Thanks Tero, Yeah now i start getting some other trouble, unable to login via root etc. but just want to know is it well-known or i am the one only happen this.

Comment: You need to take the server offline NOW. There are thousands of malware variants and people simply rebuild their servers instead of spending time analysing things. So, you are not likely to only one to face this variant, but most likely nobody tells you that they have faced this.